# Can I restrict document types uploaded to a Sharepoint Online Document Set?

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a Document Set in SharePoint online and allowed the Document content type to the document set.

Is it possible to restrict the types of documents uploaded to the document set? I only want users to be able to upload Word 2007 documents and above and not any older versions of Word documents such as Word 2003.

Not sure if it is possible or not? I can't see of a way to restrict this from the content type or document set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using Out Of The Box (OOTB) SharePoint. I am assuming you don't have access to Central Administration.

Event handlers are a common approach but you need to a have good reason to incur the technical debt involved.

Here are some discussions of options on how you can do this if you really feel it is worth the risk and trouble.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-to-restrict-a-document-library-to-a-specific-file-type-extension

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/313c37ca-62cd-434f-9fe8-3eacc4044a63/can-we-restrict-specific-file-type-uploading-on-sharepoint-library?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy